# Turn off password policy in SQL command line setup

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run a command

```
Setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=****** 
      /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=******* /SAPWD=***** 
      /SQLCOLLATION=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

to change collation that is currently on my server configured. But when I am running this command, I get an error

> The specified sa password does not meet strong password requirements

Guide on confluence says that you need to turn off password policy to install local env. But I need to rebuild it without reinstallation.

Is there way to add a parameter to the command that will turn off password policy?

Comment: Why not just use a *good* password? It's good practice.

Comment: Because guide for my local env in confluence says to use the one specified by DevOps engineer. It somehow related to the services or smth that I have no knowledge about

Comment: Speak to your engineer then

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.